# How to get webform to reply to sender?

Tags: webforms

For some reason I'm stuck on this!

Is there a setting in webform so that I can simply click on reply when I receive and email from contact form?

Been out of the loop for a while for health reasons!

Comment: Wat version of webform do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

webform/emails/

E-MAIL REPLY-TO DETAILS

Component: email

Answer (score 1):

Set the from of the e-mail that is send to the e-mail that is used by the person submitting the webform. This is a token that you can use in the settings of your webform.

Comment: That sounds like a plan, what is that token? Can't find it...

Answer (score 1):

From 7.x-4.3 version the functionality to set the Reply-To header is included.

If you are below version 7.x-4.3 you can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_reply_to